# how to print paths to each leaf of binary tree?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

In the binary tree below, all nodes are empty besides leaf nodes. I am trying to output leafs to same as encoding table right next to it.

[image: This is an example of a tree]

For this method, this is what I have:

```
     public static void printCodes(MsgTree root, String encoding) {
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        System.out.println(root.payloadChar + " --is-- " + encoding);
    } else {
        if (root.left != null) {
            encoding += '0';
            printCodes(root.left, encoding);
        } if(root.right!=null) {
            encoding += '1';
            printCodes(root.right, encoding);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is the output I am getting:

---

a --is-- 0

! --is-- 0100

d --is-- 010010

c --is-- 0100101

r --is-- 01010

b --is-- 010101

---

So I believe my problem is something to do with the excess 0, how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is mutating `encoding`, so if there are two children, going to the left node will keep `0`.

You can keep `encoding` immutable like that for instance:

```
public static void printCodes(MsgTree root, String encoding) {
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        System.out.println(root.payloadChar + " --is-- " + encoding);
    } else {
        if (root.left != null) {
            printCodes(root.left, encoding + '0');
        } if (root.right!=null) {
            printCodes(root.right, encoding + '1');
        }
    }
}
```